# Two or multiple filter request Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, filter, request

Basically I have 3 filters. date range, account code, rccode. How can I be able to make filters with two or more parameters? Each of it can be blank.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm " name="account_code"><optgroup label="No Category">
    <option></option>
    @foreach($accountCodes as $accountCode)
    <option style="width:500px; font-size: 11px;" value="{{$accountCode->ac_code}}">{{$accountCode->ac_code}} - {{$accountCode->ac_description}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="responsibility_center">
    <option></option>
        @foreach($rcCodes as $rcCode)
    <option style="width:500px; font-size: 11px;" value="{{$rcCode->rc_code}}">{{$rcCode->rc_code}} - {{$rcCode->rc_acronym}} </option>
        @endforeach
</select>
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" value="" name="dt_from">
<input class="form-control input-sm" type="date" value="" name="dt_to">
```

Controller:

```
   public function dashboard(Request $request){
       $s = $request->input('s');
       $disbursement = Disbursement::search($s)
       ->paginate(20);
   }
```

Please help me find the best practice/solution for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function dashboard(Request $request){
    $disbursements = Disbursement::query();
    if($request->input('account_code')){
        $disbursements = $disbursements->where('account_code',$request->input('account_code'));
    }
    if($request->input('responsibility_center')){
        $disbursements = $disbursements->where('responsibility_center',$request->input('responsibility_center'));
    }
    if($request->input('dt_from')){
        $disbursements = $disbursements->where('dt_from','>=',$request->input('dt_from'));
    }
    if($request->input('dt_to')){
        $disbursements = $disbursements->where('dt_from','>=',$request->input('dt_from'));
    }
    $disbursements = $disbursements->paginate(20);
    return view('dashboard',compact('disbursements'));
}
```